# Induction Proof for a series expansion of a function

Tags: calculus, induction, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have done induction proofs of many different types, but trying to prove by induction that a derivative from the Taylor series expansion of a function has me stumped in terms of how to get the final step to work.

In most induction proofs we start with a base case of $n=1$, then assume $N=n$ works, then apply
$N+1$, and usually make use of the assumption to get a statement that is TRUE to prove it.

Here is the function:
$$f(x)= \ln (1+x).$$
And here is the equation we wish to apply Induction to:
$$f^{(n)}(x)= (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+x)^{n}}.$$

The approach I took was to apply $N+1$ where ever I see $n$, and the other thing that I did was
to just differentiate the equation which was straight forward, and then both were the same.
BUT i don't feel that this was a good proof because in Induction you usually make use of
step 2 the equation itself.

Hope someone can guide me or explain to me how one goes about doing an induction proof that
has derivatives involved of this sort.

Comment: I don't know why the latex code is not being interpreted, i used the online latex editor: http://www.codecogs.com/latex

Comment: Palu, you need to enclose equations in dollar signs, double dollar signs, or blocks like `align` or `gather`.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Looks as if you have the elements of a correct proof. The only doubt I have is because you express doubt. The right proof has absolutely standard induction shape: one uses the assumption that the result is true at $k$ to show it is true at $k+1$.

Comment: Hi Andre and other, when I have done induction proofs with things that were based on number theory and others, I always substituted the assumption at k, into an expression at k+1 and did manipulation to it to arrive at something TRUE, or getting back an equation from k+1 back to k. Because here all I did was put in N+1 and got an equation and then compared it by differentiating the original equation, which i guess is my assumption at k as you put it. And both were the same, but to me this just does not feel the same, I guess because my experience with other induction proofs were with algebra.

Comment: One does "substitute" the expression at $k$ into $f^{(k+1)}(x)$, by noting that the $k+1$-th derivative is the derivative of $f^{(k)}(x)$.

Comment: And by the way one should **never** (when writing up an argument) manipulate until we get something true. That is a really really bad high school habit. (Maybe writing really really was not good, I should have used more of them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you had no problem to check that the formula wich we have to proof is true for $n=1$. Wich is step 1 of our induction proof. So we go to step 2 :

We show : if $ \ \ \ \ f^{(n)}(x)= (-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(1+x)^{n}}$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$

is valid for $n$ then it is valid for $n+1$. Wich is step 2 of te induction proof.

Now knowing that $(1)$ holds we defferintiate both sides of the equation :

$f^{(n+1)}(x)= -n \cdot (-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}= (-1)^{n}\dfrac{(n)!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$

As you can see $(1)$ is valid for $n+1$.

Indeed as you claimed "in induction we make use of step 2 the equation itself" we actually used $(1)$  wich is  "the equation" and manipulated it to show that it also holds for $n+1$. As far as i understood you made the same steps. I hope this helps to convince you that you were right.

Comment: Hi, Like i said, I guess its due to the fact that I was used to doing other types of proofs, it was algebraic based, and the fact that I have used a derivative made me confused. I see now that I should just think the derivative as another operation in my toolbelt for use in induction proofs.

Comment: @Palu Yes that's the idea (:

Comment: Its just I never did an induction proof that involved using the derivative before. Thanks for all the great help everyone. This forum is one of the greatest forums in terms of getting great help. Thanks everyone so much. Palu

Answer (score 1):

The way you've described induction is a bit muddled, and I blame the fact that proofs using induction are often written very informally.

The conceptually simplest form of the principle of mathematical induction is this:

Let $S$ be a set of natural numbers with the following two properties:

1. $0\in S$
2. For all $n\in \Bbb N$, if $n\in S$ then $n+1 \in S$.

Then $S = \Bbb N$.

This principle can be recast in logical terms (as a "schema" as follows):

Let $P$ be a propositional function in $\Bbb N$. That is, for each $n\in \Bbb N$, let $P(n)$ be a statement.

Suppose that the following hold:

1. $P(0)$ is true.
2. For each $n\in \Bbb N$, if $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is true.

Then we can conclude that for each $n\in \Bbb N$, $P(n)$ is true.

In fact, it's easy to see that either of these approaches can be extended to allow any initial value, not just $0$, at the cost of having the proposition hold (or the number be an element of the set) only for numbers greater than some value (in your case $1$).

Using one of these somewhat more formal approaches to induction should help you keep a clear idea in your mind of how you need to approach the proof.

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $$f^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$$. Prove first that $P(1)$ is true. Then prove that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, if $P(n)$ is true then so is $P(n+1)$.